# After login in to the website it is redirecting to the correct page according to inspect "network", however getting logged out and reloads login page

Tags: php, laravel, routes

After login in to the website it is redirecting to the correct page according to inspect "network". However it's getting logged out and reloads the login page.

I am using Laravel 5.1 and here is the code of AuthController.php.

Can you find out what is wrong with this? It should redirect to "admin_message" and it is in the New Routegroup.

```
/**
 * View login page
 */
protected function index(){
    if(\Auth::check()){
        return \Redirect::route('admin_messages');
    }else{
        return view('auth/login');
    }
}

/**
 * View login page
 */
protected function verifylogin(){
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
    );
    $validator = \Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    
    if($validator->fails()){
        return \Redirect::route('login_index')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
    }else{
        if (\Auth::attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']))){
            $user = User::find(\Auth::id());
            \Auth::setUser($user);
    
            $user->login_count = $user->login_count +1;
            $user->save();
            
            return \Redirect::route('admin_messages');
        }
        return \Redirect::route('login_index')
        ->with('error_message', 'Invalid email/password. Please try again.')
        ->withInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Auth::setUser()` doesn't touch your session. so It redirects to log in view. You want to instead be calling `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: Hey, thanks, I tried that, however, it is still the same though. And before it was Auth::setUser() which was working fine but don't know what happen to it suddenly. The login page reloads even after login, doesn't redirect to where it is supposed to.

Comment: Yo man, check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dU4A2J9TZCqS2Dr_wTg8BZbP5TkGavy1/view?usp=sharing) out what happens after I log in

Comment: Is there an unexpected 302 redirect? this might be a new issue. this happens for many ambiguous reasons.

Comment: Nope, it just logging out, it is supposed to open the inquiries page which is named as "admin_message"  in the route. The First 3 redirects are 302 redirects and I don't know why!

Comment: Do you think there might be any server-side issue?

Comment: it redirects to inquiries, then redirects to logout. From experience, this could happen for some misconfiguration.

Comment: I do understand that, mate. Do you have any idea to debug this certain issue?